# How to fix an issue of images from cache not being displayed in my PWA?

Tags: javascript, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I am just starting out with making PWAs.

I am using Workbox to make my first PWA which is a very basic news-fetching app.

I am using [newsapi.org](https://newsapi.org) for the news data and workbox to make my service worker.

I have managed to get everything work offline as desired except the images.

While the **images are being cached properly,they are not being displayed** when offline mode is activated.

Here is my **app.js** file :

```
const main = document.querySelector('main');
const sourceSelector = document.querySelector('#sourceSelector');
const defaultSource = 'the-washington-post';

window.addEventListener('load', e =>{
  updateNews();
  console.log('app file');
  updateSources();
  sourceSelector.value = defaultSource;

  sourceSelector.addEventListener('change', e=>{
    updateNews(e.target.value);
  })

  if('serviceWorker' in  navigator){
    try {
      navigator.serviceWorker.register('sw.js');
      console.log('SW Registered');
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('SW Registration failed');
    }

  }
});

async function updateSources(){


  const res = await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/sources?apiKey=MyApiKey
`);
  const json = await res.json();
  sourceSelector.innerHTML = json.sources.map(src => `<option value =     "${src.id}">${src.name}</option>`).join('\n');
  console.log(json);
}

async function updateNews(source = defaultSource){
    const res= await fetch(`https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?  sources=${source}&apiKey=MyApiKey`);
    const json = await res.json();
    main.innerHTML = json.articles.map(createArticle).join('\n');

};

function createArticle(article){
  return `
    <div class="article">
        <a href="${article.url}">
            <h2>${article.title}</h2>
            <img src="${article.urlToImage}">
              <p>${article.description}</p>
    </a>
  </div>
  `;


}
```

And here is my **Service Worker file (sw.js)** :

```
importScripts('https://storage.googleapis.com/workbox-  cdn/releases/3.0.0/workbox-sw.js');
const staticAssets = [
  './',
  './style.css',
  './app.js',
  './fallback.json',
];
workbox.precaching.precacheAndRoute(staticAssets
);

workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp('.*\.js'),


  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({

  })
);
workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  new RegExp ('https://newsapi.org/'),

  workbox.strategies.networkFirst({

  })
);


workbox.routing.registerRoute(
  /.*\.(png|jpg|jpeg|svg|gif)/,
  workbox.strategies.staleWhileRevalidate({
    cacheName: 'news-images',
    plugins: [
      new workbox.expiration.Plugin({
        maxEntries: 50,
        maxAgeSeconds: 12 * 60 * 60,
      })
    ],
  })
);
```

Screenshot of the problem ( As can be seen,the cache for images has been populated properly,but I can't seem to get them to display when offline)

[image]

Any help on how to remedy this would be much appreciated.

Comment: did you compare the image urls of the cache and the one which are requested by your page (see nework tab), do they match?

Comment: @StefChäser yes the image urls match.After examining it a bit more,the problem seems to arise from the "maxAgeSeconds" in the workbox expiration plugin.
Without "maxAgeSeconds" in the workbox expiration plugin the cached images are being displayed when offline.But with it,although the cache is populated,the images are not being displayed when offline

Answer (score 0):

You can debug this a little further by adding the following to your service worker:

```
// Force development builds
workbox.setConfig({ debug: true });
// The most verbose - displays all logs.
workbox.core.setLogLevel(workbox.core.LOG_LEVELS.debug);
```

Then check the logs for when an image is requested and see what the flow of that request is.

Would also be helpful if you could provide information or a screenshot of an image in the Network panel when it's failing.